# How can I use a template component with objects in Aframe?

Tags: templates, aframe, webvr

I have been looking at the following project on GitHub:

[https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-template-component](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca-entity%20template=%22src:%20#clouds%22%3E%3C/a-entity%3E)

I am quite new to using templates.

This following code works:

```
    <script id="clouds" type="text/x-jade-template">
      - for (var x = -5; x < 5; x++) {
        - for (var z = -5; z < 5; z++) {
            a-entity(geometry="primitive: box; depth: 8; height: 1; width: 6", material="opacity: 0.2", position="#{x * 20} 15 #{z * 20}")
        - }
      - }
    </script>
```

But when I use an 3D object, it does not work:

```
    <a-asset-item id="cloud-01-obj" src="cloud_1.obj"></a-asset-item>

    <!-- Cloud template. -->
    <script id="clouds" type="text/x-jade-template">
      - for (var x = -5; x < 5; x++) {
        - for (var z = -5; z < 5; z++) {
            a-entity(obj-model="obj: #cloud-01-obj", position="#{x * 2} 15 #{z *2}")                  
        - }
      - }
    </script>
  </a-assets>
```

And in the scene block there is:

```
  <a-entity template="src: #clouds"></a-entity>
```

I know the 3D objects loads as there is following code in the scene & all the different objects are loaded.

```
  <!-- cloud instances -->
  <a-entity obj-model="obj: #cloud-01-obj" position="5.0 0.0 -1" rotation="0 30 0"></a-entity>
  <a-entity obj-model="obj: #cloud-02-obj" position="5.0 1.0 5"></a-entity>
  <a-entity obj-model="obj: #cloud-03-obj" position="7.0 2.0 5"></a-entity>
  <a-entity obj-model="obj: #cloud-04-obj" position="8.0 3.0 5"></a-entity>
  <a-entity obj-model="obj: #cloud-05-obj" position="13.0 2.0 6" ></a-entity>
  <a-entity obj-model="obj: #cloud-06-obj" position="12.0 2.0 -1" </a-entity>
  <a-entity obj-model="obj: #cloud-07-obj" position="-2.0 4  0" ></a-entity>
  <a-entity obj-model="obj: #cloud-08-obj" position="-10.0 0.0 0" ></a-entity>
  <a-entity obj-model="obj: #cloud-09-obj" position="-9.0 4.0 0" ></a-entity>
```

Comment: Open the DOM inspector and look inside `<a-entity template="src: #clouds">`. What does the rendered HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a an extra space in the string.

a-entity(obj-model="obj:#cloud-09-obj", position="#{x * 2} 15 #{z *2}")

Comment: I recommend specifying the Nunjucks engine. I think it has the best API if you need interpolation.

`<a-entity obj-model="obj: #cloud-09-obj" position="{{ x* 2 }} 15 {{ z * 2 }}"></a-entity>`